# New build, BIOS crashing, can't install Windows nor Linux

Tags: boot, bios, computer-building

First time builder. Experiencing inconsistent symptoms, lost as to what to do. This is what I have experienced:

- Most commonly (around 4/5 attempts or more): power is on, the motherboard is stuck displaying CPU, DRAM or VGA debug LED with no signal to the display.
- When I manage to boot in - BIOS, I can navigate it for a while, but then it freezes and becomes unresponsive. When BIOS freezes, the CPU fans start spinning at max speed.
- When trying to install Windows 10 from a bootable USB drive, and there is a signal to the monitor, I usually see blank blue screen. After restarting many times I saw bsod with an error a few times. Once managed to get past the language selection stage, but then got an error saying unable to retrieve disk information. Meanwhile my SSD is visible from Bios with no apparent issues. After a few minutes the pc turns off.
- When trying to install Ubuntu 22 from a bootable USB drive, I saw GNU GRUB menu a few times. After selecting one of the options the screen goes black.

[image: PC Parts list] Every component is new.

Here's what I have tried:

- Unmounting the GPU and connecting the monitor to the motherboard directly via the DisplayPort cable.
- Checking connections and re-seating every component.
- Checking pins on the motherboard - none appear to be bent.
- Inserting RAM sticks into different slots. (A2,B2 is the recommended configuration, but I've tried other as well, including trying single sticks)
- Clearing CMOS by bridging the pins.
- Updating BIOS using Asus EZ Flash from inside BIOS.
- Updating and reinstalling the newest - BIOS version using Asus' - BIOS flashback feature.
- Checking CPU temperatures - around 45-50C while in BIOS.
- Enabling/Disabling XMP settings. Lowering RAM speed manually.
- Enabling/Disabling fast boot and secure boot options.
- Booting without the keyboard.
- Resetting many times.
- Powering the CPU only using the 8(4+4) pin cable, or adding either right or left half of the second 8(4+4) cable into the 4-pin slot on the motherboard.
- Making two versions of Ubuntu USB drive, once with MBR partitioning and once with GPT.
- Running a memtest86 on one RAM stick in A2 slot. The test ran for over two hours, and no issues were detected. The fact that it ran for so long without crashing surprised me, since I thought my system was very unstable based on the previous symptoms?

The motherboard is currently outside of the case, in order to have better access to all cables. The issues persisted both when mounted inside the case and now.

I don't have another desktop, so I can't test the components individually.

Advice is desperately wanted. Many thanks.

Comment: Have you considered taking it to a PC shop? They'll have a test bench ready to test every component individually.

Comment: @midrare Yes, but given that this is my first build, I want to make sure that I haven't missed anything first.

Comment: The fact that you cannot even get to BIOS, or when you do, it freezes, indicates a low-level problem. Don't bother trying to install an OS on SSD. You might try *booting* from USB (*not* installing), such as live Ubuntu, https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/ , simply to test if there are issues with SSD.

Comment: Did you connect the 4 or 8pin header for the CPU power to the PSU? Silly question, I know, but i've seen this before when the CPU power cable isn't connected.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I think this is what I've done. Sometimes I can get to the GNU menu, but after I select the option "Try or Install Ubuntu", the screen goes black and all debug lights on the motherboard turn off while CPU fan and RAM LEDs are still on.
I've just tried making another bootable Ubuntu USB with CGP partition instead of MBR, but results are the same.

Comment: @spikey_richie The motherboard has an 8 pin and a 4 pin slot, while the PSU comes with two 8 (4+4) cables. I connected only one cable to the 8 pin slot. 

I just tried connecting left and right halves of the second cable into the 4 pin slot, and the results are the same. I did not get any custom 8 to 8+4 cables, since the instructions on the PSU, and most guides that I followed, warned against using 3rd party cables.

Comment: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/shopping/guarantees-returns/index_en.htm  If you bought a product or a service online or outside of a shop (by telephone, mail order, from a door-to-door salesperson), you have the right to cancel and return your order within 14 days, for any reason and without a justification.  This applies to the stuff you bought already and parts you want to test with. You can just buy a few parts, change them out to check if that fixes the problem and if not return them.

Comment: `Updating BIOS using Asus EZ Flash from inside BIOS` yet, BIOS freezes after "a while" - you're lucky, if it froze while upgrading BIOS, you'd have a brick for a motherboard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was cause by a defective RAM stick. I must have grabbed the same faulty stick twice when I was performing manual tests on them individually. The system works well with a new ram kit. Lessons learned:

1. **Make sure to label the RAM sticks and just run the memtest on them, instead of trying to test anything manually.**
2. **Have a small cooler with nice ram clearance just for building purposes, as with mine I had to unmount the cooler every time I needed to change ram configuration.**